# wrong/none texture UV mapping

Tags: uv, texture-coordinates

[image: I made it many times before and it worked properly]

I am trying to map mamooth fur texture to my model using 'Project from View' function.
Wherever I move selected faces in left window, the result in right window stays unchanged.
Can anybody explain me, what mistake am I doing? Thanx

Comment: It looks like it is the same image, so I suspect that the same UV map is not being edited and used. Check the mesh data and see if there is more than one UV map.

Comment: Thank you! I do not know what I actually made but according to your advice I found and deleted some UV-maps in ObjectDataProperties and it worked!!!

Comment: your welcome. You can add the solution as an answer to your own question to help future stackexchange users.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the same UV map was being edited and used.
I found two different UV maps in MeshData-ObjectDataProperties.
Removing of the second UV-map solved my problem!